# Convert QString to QByteArray with forced locale

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I need to convert QString to QByteArray using cp1251 locale without toLocal8bit() function.

I.e. on my current PC default locale is cp1251 -> QString::toLocal8bit() is working great, but once I switch locale to something different -> I cannot use toLocal8Bit(). I've read documentation about QTextCodec and stuff, but it seems very obscure to me.

So, the question is - how do I convert from QString to QByteArray using specified locale?

Any help and explanation will be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out yourself, you'll need [`QTextCodec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html) for this. What you want to do should be as simple as this:

```
QString src = "My test string";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(src);
```